# AngularJS ui-router : Could not resolve___ from state ___ Error

Tags: angularjs, pug, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am following along on this year old ui-router tutorial http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/ and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'settings/quotes' from state 'settings'
```

[image]

I am fitting this tutorial app into my Express.JS setup and I'm using Jade for my templates.

All the Jade templates seem to be rendering properly but I am noticing that there is no `href` being created for the **User Quotes** (`settings/quotes` URL) `ui-sref` link. Maybe there is a clue there. You can see this in the below screenshot:

[image]

I will post all key files below.

---

### AngularJS Files

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            var settings = {
                name: 'settings',
                url: '/settings',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: '/partials/settings',
                controller: 'SettingsController'
            };

            var details = {
                name: 'settings.details',
                parent: settings,
                url: '',
                templateUrl: '/partials/settings-details'
            };

            var quotes = {
                name: 'settings.quotes',
                parent: settings,
                url: '/quotes',
                templateUrl: '/partials/settings-quotes'
            };

            $stateProvider
                .state(settings)
                .state(details)
                .state(quotes);
}])
.controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        name: "Bob Loblaw",
        email: "boblaw.bob@loblaw.org",
        password: "semi secret",
        quotes: "I am making it happen now!"
    };
}]);
```

### Jade Templates

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html 
html
    include head
    body(ng-app='app')
        p From the layout.jade file
        <div ui-view></div>
        include scripts
```

**settings.jade**

```
ul
    li Settings
    li 
        a(ui-sref="settings") User Details
    li 
        a(ui-sref="settings/quotes") User Quotes
    div(ui-view="")
```

**settings-details.jade**

```
h3 {{user.name}}\'s Quotes
hr
div
    label Quotes
        textarea(type="text", ng-model="user.quotes")
button(ng-click="done()") Save
```

**settings-quotes.jade**

```
h3 {{user.name}}\'s Details
hr
div
    label Name
        input(type="text", ng-model="user.name")
div
    label Email
        input(type="text", ng-model="user.email")
button(ng-click="done()") Save
```

### ExpressJS Server

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
path = require('path');
```

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

```
// configuration
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('dev')); // logs every request to console
app.use(bodyParser()); // pull information from html in POST
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// connect to mongodb via mongoose
if(env === 'development') {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/3lf');
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://maxmythic:mongolab3lf@ds033307.mongolab.com:33307/3lf');
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error ...'));
db.once('open', function(callback) {
  console.log('3lf db is open for business ...');
});

// create mongoose schema and retrieve data
var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage;
Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc){
  mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
});

// define routes
// make sure to coordinate client side and server side routes
app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res) {
  res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath); 
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    mongoMessage: mongoMessage
  });
});


var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
```

Comment: Wow, is that a real password for MongoLAB? :)

Comment: Excellent use of arrested development

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are almost there, ui-router needs this:

```
<a ui-sref="settings.details">...
```

this says `ui-sref` navigate to state named `'settings.details'`, in case we would need to pass params, it is very similar like $state.go...

```
<a ui-sref="settings.details({param1:value1, param2:value2})">...
```

if we want to use url defined for states, we still can, but we must use href

```
<a href="#/settings">...to get to details
<a href="#/settings/quotes">...to get to quotes
```

if the child url is empty string like in our case

```
     var settings = {
            name: 'settings',
            url: '/settings',
            abstract: true,
            ...
        };

     var details = {
            name: 'settings.details',
            parent: settings,
            url: '',
            ...
        };
     var quotes = {
            name: 'settings.quotes',
            parent: settings,
            url: '/quotes',
            ...
        };
```

See documentation:

#### [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)

or [new doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) *(cite)*

> `ui-sref='stateName'` - Navigate to state, no params. `'stateName'` can be any valid absolute or relative state, following the same syntax rules as $state.go()

Comment: Thank you Radim. Using the dot notation state name `settings.details` and `settings.quotes` worked for me :)

Comment: Great to see that ); Enjoy `ui-router`, really awesome tool ;)

Comment: I had the same problem. You'd think they would mention such a basic thing on the getting started page!